# How to bound the following sum

Tags: number-theory

I am interested in bounding the sum

$$S(x)=\sum_{i\leq x}\vert\{x/i\}-\{x/(i+1)\}\vert$$

where $\{x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$.

A calculation on MATHEMATICA seems to suggest $$S(x)=O(x^\theta)$$

where $\theta$ is some real number less than 1.

**Question:** Is there any theoretical evidence for such a conjecture?

Comment: The contribution of summands $i>\sqrt x$ should be approximately $2\sqrt x$ because for these we *can* ignore the absolute value most of the time and get about one extra each time $x/i$ crosses an integer. Thius suggests $S(x)\le 3\sqrt x$

Comment: @ y zhao : This question is intriguing... what led you to this question?

Comment: @Assaultous2: Terence Tao once wrote on moebius function in his [blog](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/an-elementary-inequality-involving-the-mobius-function/), and he stated that $\{x/i\}$ has bounded variation, which is key to the proof of the identity $\sum\mu(n)/n=0$. The statement of Tao is the motivation of this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have 
$$
\begin{align}
S(x)&=\sum _{i\le x}\left|\{\tfrac xi\}-\{\tfrac x{i+1}\}\right|\\
&= \sum _{i\le \sqrt x}\left|\{\tfrac xi\}-\{\tfrac x{i+1}\}\right|+\sum _{\sqrt x <i\le x}\left|\{\tfrac xi\}-\{\tfrac x{i+1}\}\right|\\
&\le \lfloor \sqrt x\rfloor+\sum_{1\le k\le \sqrt x}\sum_{\frac x{k+1}<i\le \frac xk} \left|\{\tfrac xi\}-\{\tfrac x{i+1}\}\right|\\
&\le\lfloor \sqrt x\rfloor+\sum_{1\le k\le \sqrt x}\left(1+\sum_{\frac x{k+1}<i\le \frac xk-1} \left|\bigl\{\tfrac xi\bigr\}-\bigl\{\tfrac x{i+1}\bigr\}\right|\right)\\
&=\lfloor \sqrt x\rfloor+\sum_{1\le k\le \sqrt x}\left(1+\sum_{\frac x{k+1}<i\le \frac xk-1} \left|\frac xi-\frac x{i+1}\right|\right)\\
&\le \lfloor \sqrt x\rfloor+\lfloor \sqrt x\rfloor+\sum_{1\le k\le \sqrt x}\left(\frac{x}{x/(k+1)}-\frac{x}{x/k}\right)\\
&=2\lfloor \sqrt x\rfloor+\sum_{1\le k\le \sqrt x}1\\
&= 3\lfloor \sqrt x\rfloor.
\end{align}
$$
(For the crucial step notice that $\{\alpha\}-\{\beta\}=\alpha-\beta$ if $\lfloor \alpha\rfloor = \lfloor \beta\rfloor$.)

Hence $S(x)=O(x^\theta)$ with $\theta=\frac12$.

Comment: I don't follow from line 2 to line 3... could you please explain?

Comment: @Assaultous2 The fist sum has $\sqrt x$ summands $\le 1$. The second is just regrouped (for each $i$, there is exactly one $k$ such that $\frac x{k+1}<i<\frac xk$).

Comment: Numerically (for $x<10^6$), it seems that $S(x)/\sqrt x$ stays well below $2$ and maybe converges to somethiung like $\sqrt 3$?

Comment: I believe this may be because your square root of x bound for the small i was not very tight? ( Hence the gap between 2 and 3)

Comment: Also, a new idea. Often, for badly behaving functions in number theory, the summation of the function is studied for irregularities to cancel out ( famous example: all the sums of the divisors functions) Could anyone find a result for the asymptotic of the sum of S(x)?

Comment: @Assaultous2 Yeah, for $i<\sqrt x$ we may consider $\{x/i\}$ and $\{x/(i+1)\}$ more or less random and independant. This brings us from $\le\sqrt x$ to $\approx \frac 38\sqrt x$ or so